# awk is not matching correctly

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to awk a file which contains a list of names mapped to DOB in DD-MM format.

The match didn't work in attempt 1), so I tried to run it on the command line as per attempt 2), but that still didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
file.txt
jason 08-04
```

## ATTEMPT 1

```
XXXXXX$ cat a.txt
#!/bin/bash

file="file.txt"

current_date=$(date +%d-%m)
awk -F" ", 'if ($2==$current_date) print $1)' "$file"
```

## ATTEMPT 2

```
awk -F" ", '{
if ($2=='08-04')
   print "$1"
}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues in both your *attempts*:

*Attempt#1* issues:

- the variable `$current_date` was not interpolated within single quotes
- misplaced comma after field separator `awk -F" ",` <--
- attempt to use `if` operator outside the awk's action delimiters `{ ... }` - will throw `syntax error ...`

*Attempt#2* issues:

- misplaced comma after field separator `awk -F" ",` <--
- broken single quoting `'...'08-04'...'`

The right way (passing a variable into awk command as an argument):

```
awk -v d="$curr_date" '$2==d{ print $1 }' "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

For attempt 1, you'll need to use double quotes for the variable to be expanded by the shell, but that will cause problems with things like `$1`.
I'd suggest rewriting it so:

```
awk -v current_date="$(date +%d-%m)" '$2 == current_date {print $1}' "$file"
```

Here, we set an awk variable `current_date` using the `-v` option.

In attempt 2, using single quotes inside the single-quoted string just exited the quote. You should use double quotes for awk strings, and shouldn't quote `$1`:

```
awk '$2 == "08-04" {print $1}' file.txt
```

In both attempts, I don't understand why you use `-F" ",`. By default, awk splits on whitespace, so you can just omit the field separator for the example input shown and the `,` is entirely superfluous. Also, often awk expressions like `{if (A) B}` can be  rewritten as just `A {B}`, which is more idiomatic for awk.